# Pretrain a Stable Baseline 3 SAC algo from recorded historical / real-life data

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I currently have a database recorded from human behavioural (observation, action, reward, next action) with 400k examples collected in real-life conditions.

I want to implement a kind of pretraining function for SAC algorithm from Stable Baselines 3 but it seems Imitation API (https://imitation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does not correspond exactly what i'm looking for for some reasons :

- Imitation Learning is designed to reproduce a behaviour from (observation, action) couple and does not use recorded reward.
- AIRL and GAIL does not support variable horizons (Actually, it seems true for almost all imitation algos)
- SQIL can be unstable with continuous action spaces algorithms like SAC.

I read the paper "Accelrating inverse reinforcement learning with expert boostrapping" (   arXiv:2402.02608, Wu, Sanjiban 2024, URL : https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.02608). The proposed solution seems close of what i'm looking for. To make it short the concept is based on two principles :

- Expert Replay Boostrapping (ERB)
- Expert Q Boostrapping (EQB)

ERB seems easy to implement because it's no more than pre-filling the replay buffer with historical data but I don't know how to implement EQB... (Maybe training critic independantly before training actor ?)

Moreover, i read somwhere feedeing an RL algo with only "good" examples (especially without cases of illegal actions) could lead to instability...

Could someone help me on this point ?

Thanks.